# What is the best way to debug an office js add-in for Excel 2016 on a windows 7 machine?

Tags: office-js

We are currently using notification messages to debug the add-in in Windows 7. The add-in is developed using angular and sometimes the angular error causes the app not to load. Since the developer console is not available, it makes it difficult to debug. Saw this link: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10 which talks about debugging in windows 10. Are there similar approach available for Windows 7 and IE 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Angular, I assume you're using Node + NPM + VSCode (or other) as your editor?  Basically, and I correct to assume that you aren't using the Visual Studio template, and hence can't do the usual "F5" debugging?  And that instead, you want to **attach** to an already-running Add-in?

Steps (and we are exploring whether we can provide easier options in the future):

- Close all instances of Internet Explorer
- Go to Visual Studio -> Debug -> Attach to process
- Be sure to select "Attach to": "Script code"
- Select all the iexplore.exe instances
- Click "Attach"

You should now get a full debugging experience, complete with console output ("JavaScript console" window; use the Quick Launch (<kbd>ctrl-Q</kbd>) to launch it if it doesn't display be default), DOM Explorer (again, use Quick Launch if you don't see it), and more.

[image]

Comment: Debugging JavaScript is still an issue. Came across scenarios where angular injection is breaking in some places and it was hard to reproduce due to dependencies to Office context.

Comment: I'd be curious to learn more (though fair warning, it might be a bit before I can really investigate).  Feel free to email me if you can provide some specific examples.  Email is firstname.lastname@microsoft.com

Comment: When using Visual Studio template, is there a way to open a template instead of a blank workbook?